# The homology group of $K^3=RP^3\#RP^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it right? $H_0\cong H_3\cong\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$, $H_2\cong0$.

Comment: Yes. There is a general formula for the (co)homology of a connected sum you can probably guess from this. Great manifold, by the way, that one.

Comment: @Mike Miller Thank you always!